# Jquery not loading / running on Wordpress home page

Tags: jquery

I'm hoping someone can help. I'm trying to get some animation on scroll working with a jQuery script I found. I think I've managed to get it to read `$` and `jQuery` as Wordpress runs in NoConflict mode, but so far I am unable to get the script to do anything.

Here is the JS:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(function() {

  var $window           = $(window),
      win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
      isTouch           = Modernizr.touch;

  if (isTouch) { $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('.animated'); }

  $window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);

  function revealOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
        win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;

    // Showed...
    $(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;

      if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
        if ($this.data('timeout')) {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
            $this.addClass('.animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
          }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
        } else {
          $this.addClass('.animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
        }
      }
    });
    // Hidden...
   $(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
      if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
        $(this).removeClass('.animated .fadeInUp .flipInX .lightSpeedIn')
      }
    });
  }

  revealOnScroll();
});

        });
```

I'm not great with jQuery, but any pointer would be great. I'm pretty sure the problem lies within the script and no classes are added or removed.

Comment: what is written in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized the script twice. Here is the updated script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $window           = $(window),
win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
isTouch           = Modernizr.touch;

if (isTouch) { $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('.animated'); }

$window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);

function revealOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
    win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;

    // Showed...
    $(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
        var $this     = $(this),
        offsetTop = $this.offset().top;

        if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
            if ($this.data('timeout')) {
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $this.addClass('.animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
                }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
            } else {
                $this.addClass('.animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
            }
        }
    });
   // Hidden...
   $(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
       var $this     = $(this),
       offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
       if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
           $(this).removeClass('.animated .fadeInUp .flipInX .lightSpeedIn')
       }
   });
}

revealOnScroll();
});
```

**UPDATE:** 
This script is not working because you have used jQuery script inside Javascript which won't work. You need to use either javascript or jQuery.

revealOnScroll() is a javascript function while .each used inside this function is a jQuery function. Please be clear whether you want to use jQuery or javascript.

**UPDATE 1:**

Add this script after jquery.js which you have missed.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mehul Gohil, Ive just tried adding this and it doesnt seem to make a difference. Here is the link http://dev.silverfx.co.uk if you dont mind taking a look for me. Thank you

Comment: @Jonnygogo: I have added an update to my answer at the end. Please check. Thanks

Comment: I copied the code straight from here, http://codepen.io/benske/pen/yJoqz I didnt think i had made any changes and it works fine here?

Comment: @Jonnygogo: Check UPDATE 1 in the answer

Comment: Perfect @Mehul Gohil, i was convinced this was included already but clearly my mistake, thanks very much for you help!